# AngularJS HTTP 415

Tags: angularjs

Estou com problema para fazer uma requisição GET, ficando dando erro 415 (Unsupported Media Type).

Apesar de já ter setado os headers ele parece não respeitar.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão do que fazer para resolver o problema? Lembrando sou novato no AngularJS

```
$http.get('https://minhaurl.com.br/api/v1/tasks', 
            {
                headers: { 
                    'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                }
            }
        );
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vejo que seria interessante colocar também o código que você tem no servidor que é chamado por essa requisição.

Comment: @GiancarloAbelGiulian a aplicação do server back-end é privada, nem mesmo eu tenho acesso há ela, quando eu faço um request via ajax (jQuery) vai sem problemas. Eu consegui resolver o problema temporariamente de uma forma totalmente errada, eu fui no arquivo AngularJS line: 11.949 onde ele declara os `headers` e adicionei um `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, depois de muito procurar eu encontrei uma 'gambiarra melhor' ... na hora de setar as options do HTTP método GET você deve passar Data em branco '', automaticamente ele irá trocar o content-type para application/json utf8

Mais o menos assim:

```
 $http({
   method: 'GET',
   data: '',
   url: 'https://minhaurl.com.br/api/v1/tasks'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
 $http({
       method: 'GET', 
       url: 'https://minhaurl.com.br/api/v1/tasks',
       headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json' 
       }
    });
```

Comment: Amigo, ainda continua no mesmo problema. Eu consegui resolver o problema temporariamente de uma forma totalmente errada, eu fui no arquivo AngularJS line: 11.949 onde ele declara os header e adicionei um `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`